# Using stdin instead of a file in a python call to a perl script

Tags: python, perl, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm running a perl script that accepts a file as input from Python using subprocess.Popen(). I now need the input to the script to accept input from the standard input and not a file. If I run the perl scrip from the shell like this:

```
perl thescript.perl --in /dev/stdin --other_args other_values
```

It works perfectly. However, in python, nothing happens using the following commands:

```
mytext = "hi there"
args = ["perl", "myscript.perl", "--in", "/dev/stdin", "--other_args", other_values]
pipe = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = pipe.communicate(input=mytext.encode("utf8"))[0]`
```

result always returns empty (I've also tried using `pipe.stdin.write(mytext")` and `result=pipe.stdout.read()`)

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: 1- are there shell meta-characters such as spaces in `other_values`? Is it a single parameter? 2- Does `echo hi there | perl thescript.pl --in /dev/stdin ...` work?

Comment: I dunno what is wrong but I'd try either
 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT: or stderr=subprocess.PIPE 
so you will also see the errors that are happening.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, 1- other_values don't have any meta-characters. 2- Yes, in the command line with echo works.

Comment: @odedsh, I added stderr but there is no output there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by @J.F.Sebastian above, I managed to solve this problem with echo and pipes.

```
args = ["perl", "myscript.perl", "--in", "/dev/stdin", "other_args", other_vals]
pipe1 = subprocess.Popen(["echo", mytext], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
pipe2 = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=pipe1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
pipe1.stdout.close()
result = pipe2.communicate()[0]
```

Which returns the expected output. Still not sure why the original (posted in the question) didn't work (using communicate to send the text to the stdin)

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/stdin` should work (if it works in the shell on your system):

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> import sys
>>> p = Popen([sys.executable, '-c', 'print(open("/dev/stdin").read()[::-1])'],
...           stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
>>> p.communicate(b'ab')[0]
'ba\n'
```

`stdin=PIPE` creates a pipe and connects it to the child process' stdin. Reading from `/dev/stdin` is equivalent to reading from the standard input (`0` fd) and therefore the child reads from the pipe here as shown in the example.

Comment: Your example works in python, but my Perl script accepts --in <filename> as input, so I'm not sure how this will work in my case. I tried subprocess.Popen(["perl", "myscript.pl", "--in", "/dev/stdin"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) which doesn't work (communicate returns no error but no output)

Comment: @ShaniShalgi do you see `open("/dev/stdin").read()` in the answer? What do you think it does? Are you sure `subprocess.check_call("each input | perl ... --in /dev/stdin >output", shell=True)` works? (Do you see the expected output in the `output` file?)

Comment: I'm not sure we understand each other. In my question I wrote that --in "/dev/stdin" doesn't work in python. subprocess.check_call does not return, subprocess.check_output returns nothing exactly like Popen+communicate. Also, the --in parameter does not accept open("/dev/stdin").read(), only strings. Can you give me the example you mean using the myperl.pl annotation?

Comment: @ShaniShalgi ok. Let's do one small step at a time: do you see the expected output in the `output` file if you run: `subprocess.check_call("echo hi there | perl thescript.perl --in /dev/stdin >output", shell=True)`?

Comment: Yes this works! I now solved the problem using:
`pipe1 = subprocess.Popen(["echo", sentence], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
pipe2 = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "myscript.perl", "--in", "/dev/stdin"], stdin=pipe1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
pipe1.stdout.close()
result = pipe2.communicate()[0]`
Thank you for your patience and help

Comment: @ShaniShalgi there is no need to start `echo` process here. `stdin=PIPE` works as is (it means your original code does not work for reasons unrelated to `/dev/stdin` e.g., perhaps there was a typo in the command). The purpose of the `echo` command is to find out whether `perl` tries to mmap the input file (that would fail for /dev/stdin) or whether it needs a seek-able file (/dev/stdin is not seekable). Use the code in the answer (replace the command  inside `[]` with you own).

Comment: There was no typo as the same command worked in the command line, and I did not rush to post before double checking every word. The only thing I changed now is the echo instead of accepting input through communicate. It remains a mystery!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108775/discussion-between-shani-shalgi-and-j-f-sebastian).